# Query multiple rooms with different conditionals (Adults, Children)

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query where I **select available x Rooms with x Adults + x Children** per hotel that matches a date range, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to query a list of rooms per hotel like this:

- 1 Room with 2 Adults / 0 Children
- 1 Room with 4 Adults / 2 Children
- 1 Room with 2 Adults / 1 Children

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(pl.day) AS Days, p.property_ID AS Hotel_ID, 
p.name AS Hotel_Name, r.room_name AS Room_Name, r.room_type_ID AS Room_ID

FROM property p

  INNER JOIN room_type r 
    ON p.property_ID=r.property_ID
    AND (r.max_adults >= 3 AND r.max_children >= 0)

  INNER JOIN plan pl 
    ON pl.room_type_ID=r.room_type_ID
    AND (pl.day >= "2014-07-07" AND pl.day <= "2014-07-11")

GROUP BY Room_ID, Hotel_ID
HAVING Days = 4
```

**EDIT:**
The tables are:

- **property** > property_ID ...
- **plan** > property_ID | room_type_ID | day | rate | alloc | min_stay ...
- **room_type** > property_ID | max_adults | max_children ...
- ...

Comment: You may want to add the table definitions, as well as describe the expected result and the current result.

Comment: Edited my post. The expected result should be Rooms that match number of rooms given with additional Adults/Children per hotel. Right now it shows anything that matches regardless if there are less rooms than asked.

Answer (score 0):

first insert the resultset of the room_type table to a temp table with the filtering by your parameters

```
 r.max_adults >= 3 AND r.max_children >= 0
```

then query that table and join the property  and plan tables to it and it should be faster.

Comment: I have multiple parameters to filter per room though.
r.max_adults >= 3 AND r.max_children >= 0 ,
r.max_adults >= 2 AND r.max_children >= 1 , r.max_adults >= 2 AND r.max_children >= 2

Comment: Can be `(r.max_adults >= 3 AND r.max_children >= 0) OR (r.max_adults >= 2 AND r.max_children >= 1)...`

Answer (score 0):

For the tables, I guess "room_type" actually means "room" and plan means avaliable room in a particular date?

For the result, not clear what you want, guess it is about counting of rooms

So I guess it is what you want:

```
Select count(s.room_name) num_room, s.max_adults, s.max_children
FROM
(
   Select r.room_name, r.max_adults, r.max_children
   FROM property p
   INNER JOIN room_type r ON p.property_ID=r.property_ID
   INNER JOIN plan pl ON pl.room_type_ID=r.room_type_ID
   WHERE (r.max_adults >= 3 AND r.max_children >= 0)
   AND (pl.day >= "2014-07-07" AND pl.day <= "2014-07-11")
   GROUP BY r.room_name, r.max_adults, r.max_children
   HAVING count(pl.day)= 4
) s
GROUP BY s.max_adults, s.max_children
```

And result will be something like

```
num_room  max_adults  max_children
11        2           0 
2         4           2
4         2           1
```

If not, please provide simple data and result.